# Best Way to create a bounding box for object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

Currently, I am working to create a deep neural network for object detection, and i am also create my own dataset, and I use the bounding box to annotate my images, and my question is what are the rules to have the best bounding box for my images training. I mean if I wrap my object is it good to limit the background of my object or do I need t find a way to bound only my object.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not specialized in bounding box, but in general in deep learning, we try to obtain a network which will be robust against irrelevant variables, in your case, the background. Bounding should not be dependant of the background, so set your bounding box the way you want, it should be learned by the network how to replicate it.

The most important thing is more the size of the database and having consistent bounding than precise bounding.

Also if you want your network to be robust against changes of backgrounds, you should have as many backgrounds as possible, uncorrelated with the bounding.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference YOLO algorithm- this is the best algorithm for object detection. The first, input image will divide into SxS grid cell, Yolo will predict 5 bounding box for each cell and with each bounding box, Yolo also predict the center coordinates of box, width, height of box and confidence score of having any object in that box along with the probabilities that object will belong to M classes. After that, we use Non Max Suppression and IOU to calculate the accuracy between bounding box with ground truth and get only the most exactly bounding box for the object in the input image.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any rule as such but yes the best practice of proper annotation is to keep certain pixel width while creating bounding boxes.

See, the background changes are the variations in the object which will make it robust but keep in mind to have enough samples to properly recognizing the patterns in object(edges, shapes, textures, etc.)

Hope i addressed your query!